# How to use a function from one glue script to another in AWS glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark, generic-function

I have one AWS glue pyspark script for example scriptA.py. In this script I have defined few generic functions like readSourceData()

def readSourceData(parameter1, parameter2):

//logic of function

Now I want to use this generic function in my secong glue pyspark script scriptB.py.

I have many such generic functions. How can I import these functions and use them in other scripts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create modules with your generic functions and attach those external python modules to your glue jobs. More on this you can read up [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html).

Extensive answer:

1. You bundle your generic functions in a [python module](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).
2. Then you .zip the module and upload it to S3.
3. You add the path of your module in S3 to your Glue job in the Python library path field [image]

Make sure that your Job Role has access to the location in S3.

Comment: Hi Robert, Thank you so much for the link. :) But, I could not get much info from link. If possible, could you please explain the solution in detail here?

Comment: I added to my answer. Hope it is clear now :) if it helped you, an upvote and a accept would be appreciated

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks! I followed above steps but now how to call these functions in glue job?

Comment: You just import them as you would in python. From module_name import function_name

Comment: in my readSourceData function, I have one glueContext.create_dynamic_frame from Athena. When I am running the glue job, its showing an error that - In readSourceDatafunction function, 'glueContext' is not defined.

Comment: Of course you would need to define the glue context in the function or inject it.

Comment: I did pass the glueContext in the function, readSourceData(glueContext, tablename,..) but still its showing same error.

Comment: This is a problem of your code though and not the topic of this questions. Please raise another question then. An upvote or an accept on this question would be appreciated.

Comment: Accepting would be great as well :)

Comment: What is the module name in this case? There are three components to an s3 url. Is the module name bucket.prefix.object ?